# Hibernate (on postgres) dropping Schema from @JoinTable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.10.Final (with SpringData JPA) running on a Postgres 4 database and have run into a very strange bug. Our app utilizes a database outside of the default "public" schema, and when we try to insert data Hibernate drops the correct schema.

Our model consists of an abstract "Log" class that uses single class inheritance to allow many different object types to insert a associated log message. See code below.

The schema already exists (hibernate doesn't create it) and booting validation runs fine, but when try to insert a new record we get the error **relation "booking_log" does not exist** -- which is missing the schema modifier (say *customapp* for our purposes). See the first line from the logs below to get an idea of what other insert statements look like.

I've dug through the mapping phase and verified Hibernate is indeed picking up the schema from the @JoinTable annotation, but not sure how we're losing it.

Any help debugging or possible solutions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

**Log** - Abstract super class

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name="log", schema=Constants.DB_SCHEMA)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="log_type_id", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class Log {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="log_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name="log_seq_gen", sequenceName=Constants.DB_SCHEMA + ".log_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    // ...     

}
```

**BookingLog**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class BookingLog extends Log implements TenantResource<Company,Long> {

    @JoinTable(name="booking_log",
        schema = Constants.DB_SCHEMA,
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="log_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, updatable=false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="booking_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, updatable=false)})
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Booking booking;

    ///... 

    }
```

** Logs **

```
2015-07-20_18:14:09.055 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into customapp.booking_product (created_dt, created_by, modified_dt, modified_by, include_in_payroll, include_in_revenue, booking_id, description, payroll_percent, price, product_id, qty, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2015-07-20_18:14:09.072 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into booking_log (log_date, details, log_time, user_id, booking_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2015-07-20_18:14:09.176 DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute statement [n/a]
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "booking_log" does not exist
```

Comment: Based on your @JoinTable configuration the insert statement for booking_log table should be like "insert into booking_log ( log_id, booking_id) values (?, ?)". I think this is the first problem to be resolved. It is really strange that Hibernate doesn't advise that the same table name  is used twice (in your association and perhaps in other entity) so...maybe are you referencing to another entity class/package?

Comment: @Guillermo actually there are a few more fields that I omitted for brevity, so the parameters for the insert are correct. The relationship is uni-directional, so in this case Booking doesn't have a reference to logs. Could that be the problem?

Comment: It was too large to write a comment, see my answer post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your @JoinTable configuration and the insert statement that hibernate generates looks like the problem is the way you are triyng to add extra fields/data to the booking_log table.

I would need more details about your model to be sure but I think you are using a join-table and something else instead of *create a class that models the join-table*.

I mean, you have this

```
BookingLog (*) --------------------------------------> (1) Booking
```

but I think you really need this

```
BookingLog (1) ---> (1) BookingLogAssociation (*) ---> (1) Booking
```

Then the mapping will be like this,

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class BookingLog extends Log implements TenantResource<Company,Long> {

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="bookingLog")
  private BookingLogAssociation booking;

}
```

Note the attributes of **`BookingLogAssociation`**, they are the extra field/data you want to add in booking_log table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking_log")
@IdClass(BookingLogAssociationId.class)
public class BookingLogAssociation {

  @Id
  private long log_id;
  @Id
  private long booking_id;

  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="log_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  private BookingLog bookingLog;

  @ManyToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="booking_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  private Booking booking;

  @Column(name="log_date")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Calendar logDate;

  @Column(name="log_time")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
  private Calendar logTime;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
  private User user;
  // Could be just an attribute too
  //@Column(name="user_id")
  //private long userId;
  ...
}
```

The **`BookingLogAssociationId`** class that represents the BookingLogAssociation's composite key.

```
public class BookingLogAssociationId implements Serializable {

  private long log_id;

  private long booking_id;

  public int hashCode() {
    return (int)(log_id + booking_id);
  }

  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof BookingLogAssociationId) {
      BookingLogAssociationId otherId = (BookingLogAssociationId) object;
      return (otherId.log_id == this.log_id) && (otherId.booking_id == this.booking_id);
    }
    return false;
  }
```

You can read more about this option [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns)